# Why calloc works only in specific parts of the code?

Tags: c, calloc

Why the first code works fine, while the second one doesnt? The only difference is where I place `calloc` in the secondary function. The reason I ask is I would have thought that the second code is the one to work, considering the value of `divisor_number` is only known once I do the for loop in the secondary function. Could you give me a quick explanation on this one? Thank you!

Also, I am not getting any errors or warnings when running the second code. Is there a way I could get some additional information from the compiler to lead me in the right direction? Thank you!

**N.b.** Apologies for the code not being very organised from a logical stand point, just working on it to get a better grasp of a few programming concepts.

1st code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


int* save_number(int *int_number);

int main()
{
   int int_number, *divisors = 0, count_even, i;

   printf("Please enter an integer:");
   divisors = save_number(&int_number);

   for (i = 1; i <= int_number; ++i)
   {
      if (divisors[i-1] % 2 == 0 && divisors[i-1] != 0)
      {
         printf("%d\n", divisors[i-1]);
         count_even++;
      }
      continue;
   }
   printf("Total even divisors: ");
   printf("%d\n", count_even);
   return 0;
}

int* save_number(int *int_number)
{
   int i, *divisors = 0, divisor_number;
   divisors = calloc(divisor_number, sizeof *divisors);

   scanf("%d", int_number);

   for (i = 1; i <= *int_number; ++i)
   {
      if (*int_number % i == 0)
      {
         divisors[i-1] = i;
         printf("%d\n", divisors[i-1]);
         divisor_number++;
      }
      continue;
   }

   return divisors;
}
```

2nd code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


int* save_number(int *int_number);

int main()
{
   int int_number, *divisors = 0, count_even, i;

   printf("Please enter an integer:");
   divisors = save_number(&int_number);

   for (i = 1; i <= int_number; ++i)
   {
      if (divisors[i-1] % 2 == 0 && divisors[i-1] != 0)
      {
         printf("%d\n", divisors[i-1]);
         count_even++;
      }
      continue;
   }
   printf("Total even divisors: ");
   printf("%d\n", count_even);
   return 0;
}

int* save_number(int *int_number)
{
   int i, *divisors = 0, divisor_number;
   scanf("%d", int_number);

   for (i = 1; i <= *int_number; ++i)
   {
      if (*int_number % i == 0)
      {
         divisors[i-1] = i;
         printf("%d\n", divisors[i-1]);
         divisor_number++;
      }
      continue;
   }
   divisors = calloc(divisor_number, sizeof *divisors);
   return divisors;
}
```

Comment: Both code are wrong, because `divisor_number` (passed to `calloc`) is never initialised. They both have *undefined behaviour* and it is a lottery which, if any, work as intended. "the value of divisor_number is only known once I do the for loop". `divisor_number` is *never* known.

Comment: In the second version, you have UB, because `divisors` is not pointing to valid memory in the loop, when you index it.

Comment: `calloc` allocates memory, you cannot allocate memory *after* you've already tried to use said memory. you must allocate it prior.

Comment: @WeatherVane - in first segment: `*divisors = 0` initializes pointer, then `divisors = save_number(&int_number);`  returns allocated memory.  Where is the UB in first segment?

Comment: "*am not getting any errors or warnings when running the second code.*", look at *valgrind* to see the errors at the execution in **both** version

Comment: @ryyker in both sections, function `save_number()` defines `int divisor_number` which in one case is immediately passed to `calloc` and in the other case is incremented before ditto. Nowhere was a value set.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, when you do

```
divisors = calloc(divisor_number, sizeof *divisors);
```

You allocate a block of memory of size "uninitialized". It could be small or large, but it is a size that could be anything. It probably works by accident because the initialized value happens to be something huge. It is still incorrect code and you should not do that.

In the second case, when you do

```
divisors[i-1] = i;
```

divisors is not yet initialized. So it will try to write to a random memory location. That has a much smaller chance of "working by accident". Most memory address will be invalid and you get an immediate crash with high probsability.

The correct way would be to count the needed memory, then allocate it, then write to it.

Or, allocate more than you know you need, then then write to it.

Comment: `divisor_number` is uninitiaised in *both* codes. In the second was incremented but is no less undefined.

Comment: good point, but in the second case the crash will have happened even before `divisor_number` is used.

Answer (score 0):

You have several undefined behaviors in your code :

Doing

> calloc(divisor_number, sizeof *divisors);

while `divisor_number` is not yet initialized, then using the allocated block

In your second proposal also allocating the block *after* writing in it.

In case the user do not enter a valid integer, letting `*int_number` not initialized.

In case you cannot allocate the block (independently of the previous UB)

---

You can easily remove these UBs.

You know the number elements you will need to save because it is the value of the number you read

In the first code replace

> ```
>  int i, *divisors = 0, divisor_number;
>  divisors = calloc(divisor_number, sizeof *divisors);
>
>  scanf("%d", int_number);
> ```

by

```
int i, *divisors;

if ((scanf("%d", int_number) != 1) || (*int_number < 1)) {
  ..indicate error
  exit(1); 
}
if ((divisors = calloc(*int_number, sizeof *divisors)) == NULL) {
  ..indicate error
  exit(1); 
}
```

In the second code replace

> ```
> int i, *divisors = 0, divisor_number;
> scanf("%d", int_number);
> ...
>
> divisors = calloc(divisor_number, sizeof *divisors);
> ```

by

```
int i, *divisors;

if ((scanf("%d", int_number) != 1) || (*int_number < 1)) {
  ..indicate error
  exit(1); 
}
if ((divisors = calloc(*int_number, sizeof *divisors)) == NULL) {
  ..indicate error
  exit(1); 
}

...
```

I also also encourage you to remove your useless `continue;` in your loops

Answer (score 0):

Both versions of the code have errors.

In the first version you have this:

```
int i, *divisors = 0, divisor_number;
divisors = calloc(divisor_number, sizeof *divisors);
```

Here, `divisor_number` is uninitialized so its value is **indeterminate**.  Simply using the value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  You got "lucky" that things works, either because that value that happened to get passed to `calloc` was large enough to allocate enough memory, or that it wasn't big enough and that you managed not to break anything by writing past the end of allocated memory.

In the second code:

```
     divisors[i-1] = i;
     printf("%d\n", divisors[i-1]);
     divisor_number++;
```

At this point `divisiors` is set to NULL, so you're dereferencing a NULL pointer which is also undefined behavior.  Also, as in the first code, `divisor_number` is uninitialized yet you attempt to increment it.

Your posted answer also doesn't work because you're telling `calloc` to allocate 0 bytes of memory, so any access to element of the allocated array is reading past the end.

You should instead use the value read into `int_number` to allocate memory, and calling `calloc` right after doing so.  That's the actual amount of space you need.

```
int* save_number(int *int_number)
{
   int i, *divisors = 0;

   scanf("%d", int_number);
   divisors = calloc(*int_number, sizeof *divisors);

   for (i = 1; i <= *int_number; ++i)
   {
      if (*int_number % i == 0)
      {
         divisors[i-1] = i;
         printf("%d\n", divisors[i-1]);
      }
   }

   return divisors;
}
```

Comment: warning must be `calloc(*int_number...` and this is what I do in my answer (out of the fact I added tests to avoid UB if invalid number etc) ;-)

Comment: @bruno Good catch.  Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Just leaving here the final code that works, also taking into consideration @WeatherVane comment, and making sure `divisor_number` is initialised.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


int* save_number(int *int_number);

int main()
{
   int int_number, *divisors = 0, count_even, i;

   printf("Please enter an integer:");
   divisors = save_number(&int_number);

   for (i = 1; i <= int_number; ++i)
   {
      if (divisors[i-1] % 2 == 0 && divisors[i-1] != 0)
      {
         printf("%d\n", divisors[i-1]);
         count_even++;
      }
      continue;
   }
   printf("Total even divisors: ");
   printf("%d\n", count_even);
   return 0;
}

int* save_number(int *int_number)
{
   int i, *divisors = 0, divisor_number = 0;
   divisors = calloc(divisor_number, sizeof *divisors);

   scanf("%d", int_number);

   for (i = 1; i <= *int_number; ++i)
   {
      if (*int_number % i == 0)
      {
         divisors[i-1] = i;
         printf("%d\n", divisors[i-1]);
         divisor_number++;
      }
      continue;
   }

   return divisors;
}
```

Comment: doing `divisors = calloc(divisor_number, sizeof *divisors);` when `divisor_number = 0` you allocate a block sized 0